# Show the weekdays of every week of a month flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I only Display the Date and the day without the time in flutter. And I want a list of only a week of a month displayed and when the week end, the next round of week will be displayed. Also, when I push a button in one value of a list everything will be the same and all of the button will disappear, I just want to edit one line, can someone please help me.
any answer is appreciated. thank you.

```
 DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('MM/dd (E)');
 final items = List.generate(7, (i) {
 DateTime date = DateTime.now();
 return formatter.format(date.add(Duration(days: i)));
});
 body:
  Column(children: <Widget>[
    Text('Humpty Dumpty', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
    Expanded( child:
      ListView.builder(
      itemCount: items.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Wrap (
            spacing: 20, // to apply margin in the main axis of the wrap
            runSpacing: 20, // to apply margin in the cross axis of the wrap
            children: <Widget>[Text('${items[index]}'),Text('${text.toString()}')]),
          trailing:
          Visibility(
              visible: viewVisible,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('登　録'),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.indigo[700],
                ), onPressed: () {
                if (viewVisible) {
                  ButtonClicked();
                }
                _awaitReturnValueFromSecondScreen(context);
              },
          )),
        );
        },
      )
    )
  ]
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: What is your exact problem in doing that? What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: final items = List<DateTime>.generate(30, (i) {
      DateTime date = DateTime.utc(
        DateTime.now().year,
        DateTime.now().month,
        DateTime.now().day,
      );

This is my code and it display like 
2021-08-27 00:00:00.000Z

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `intl` package to format date.

int package link: https://pub.dev/packages/intl/install

and use it like this:

import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

```
main() {
  final DateFormat df= DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
  final String formated= df.format(DateTime.now());
  print(formated); // print 2021-08-27
}
```

also you can use code like this:

```
print(DateFormat.yMMMd().format(DateTime.now()));
```

for more details read this:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Try below code without using third package library

```
DateTime today = new DateTime.now();
String date =
    "${today.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}/${today.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}/${today.year.toString()}";
//print your date
 print(date);
```

your output => 27/08/2021

with using third package
0

You should add DateFormat intl: ^0.17.0 dependency [here](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) in your pubspec.yaml file

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(now);
print(formattedDate);
```

Your output look like this : 27-08-2021